# Is there something like nameof of C# in C for define directive?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, nameof

I have the classic

```
    #define SOME_CONSTANT value
```

Is there a way to get the string `"SOME_CONSTANT"` like the C# `nameof(field)`?

**EDIT**

I have to parse a file looking for some keyword:

```
#define KEY_A 1
#define KEY_B 2

int foo(char *s)
{
    if (strcmp(s, nameof(KEY_A)) == 0)
        return KEY_A;
    else if (strcmp(s, nameof(KEY_B)) == 0)
        return KEY_B;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

if i call `foo("KEY_A")` it should return 1

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Comment: `#define SOME_CONSTANT_NAME "SOME_CONSTANT"` is about as close as you're going to get.

Comment: The reason C# has this and C doesn't is because C# has [*metadata,*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/metadata-and-self-describing-components) while C does not.  Once your program has been compiled, the name of the constant is gone.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that @RobertHarvey, but I guess it's not possible :(
Thank you anyway, you both.

Comment: Consider going one step back and asking about help on whatever you are trying to achieve. I think we might be looking at a XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem This is nothing bad, it means that there might actually be a cool easy way to achieve your actual goal.

Comment: You can `#define NAMEOF(X) #X`, and then `NAMEOF(SOME_CONSTANT)` will expand to `"SOME_CONSTANT"`. I'm not sure if that's what you really want.

Comment: ... My `NAMEOF(X)` suggestion is probably not what you want because it isn't nestable. So after `#define NAMEOF(X) #X` and `#define FOO(X) X`, `NAMEOF(FOO(SOME_CONSTANT))` would expand to `"FOO(X)"`, which is very unlikely to be what you want. Similarly, after `#define NAMEOF(X) #X` and `#define XFOO(X) X` and `#define FOO(X) XFOO(X)`, `NAMEOF(FOO(SOME_CONSTANT))` would expand to `"FOO(SOME_CONSTANT)"`, which may be a slight improvement, but still unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: @IanAbbott, your NAMEOF(X) #X seems to work exactly as I want because I don't need it to handle nested stuff, I just have some keywords that I have to match in a file and convert them to int values, now I try it!

Comment: @IanAbbott I tested your solution and it works, if you want you can write it as an answer, or I'll do it myself

Comment: Why write `nameof(KEY_A)` when you can write `"KEY_A"`?

Comment: @n.m. That's what I'm wondering too, which is why I'm loath to submit my suggestion as a answer. (The only thing I can think of is that maybe OP is listing the symbols in a file wrapped as a macro call, and `#include`ing the file more than once with different definitions of the macro.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no-one else has posted the answer...

@palmis, I think this is the solution that you were seeking.

```
#define NAMEOF(x) (#x)
```